# CRM 2011 and SharePoint using document management from CRM SDK

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm-2011, document-management

I need to test the CRM 2011 and SharePoint document management performance. So I hooked up CRM and SharePoint together using `Document list` component.

And now I need to upload a document into SharePoint (not attachment) using CRM SDK.

Is there any solutions, or even a little piece of code which uploads a document into a SharePoint document list?

Sultan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is:

Create the Sharepoint Document Location (related to the SP Site) with a relative url (via CRM SDK).

Turn the file into a byte array and then I feed that to my HTTP PUT method to get the file up to sharepoint:

```
private NetworkCredential loginCredentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password, domain);

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = loginCredentials;
wc.UploadData(destinationUrl, "PUT", fileData);
```

destinationUrl is where I want it to go (http:\\spite\accounts\RyanonRails\examplefile.txt), fileDate is a byte[]. Make sure the user you're using has Full Control (so it can upload).

This method works great when you receive a report from SSRS.

Sidenote: When I tried to use the actual sharepoint 2010 copy.asmx web service it failed to work cross domain.

Comment: The resulting upload has 1 Kb of size though the real file about 1 Mb

Comment: I used `File.ReadAllBytes(uploadfile);` to read file contents and it worked